# Redemption Load Msg to RDOMail

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am trying to load Msg file to MailItem, I cannot find any method that can load from Stream or Array. I am forced to save the file on the Client PC.
OOM I used

```
Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(path, Type.Missing)
```

I can delete the temp file right after the MailItem is created.
RDO I found code

```
Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(path);
```

I cannot delete the Msg file right after the RDOMail is created. I am coding in C#, how should I dispose the Msg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile` uses the MSG file for as long as the `RDOMAil` object is alive. After you are done using it, either release it using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` or cast `RDOMail` to `IDisposable` and call `IDisposable.Dispose`.

The equivalent to Outlook's `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` would be to create a new message in one of the Outlook folders (`RDOFolder.Items.Add`), and then import the MSG file using `RDOMail.Import`.

Comment: Thank you! Dmitry. `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(msg);` is not working.   `var dis = msg as IDisposable; dis.Dispose();` works. I wonder if I use Dispose instead of Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail) will get rid of Outlook crashing problem. Someone have more that half million items in their box. Do you have comment on this?

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject will work fine as long as you don't have any dangling references to the same message.